# CFWheels: Map table to another database Database.tablename

Tags: coldfusion, cfwheels

I have a datasource called "cforms" which has access to two database
"cforms" and "cquizes"

I wish to create the following query:

```
select * from cquizes.tb_depts;
```

I have a model for table "tb_depts":

```
<cfcomponent extends="Model">
    <cffunction name="init">
        <cfset table("tb_depts")>
    </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

And my controller:

```
list = model("tb_depts").findAll(order="id");
```

When I run this controller/action. It gives me the following error:

```
[Macromedia][Oracle JDBC Driver][Oracle]ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

And it generates the following query:

```
 SELECT * FROM tb_depts
```

I understand what the problem is because since "tb_depts" doesn't exist in database "cforms" it throws that not found error. However is there are way to tell the model that using the datasource "cforms" access database "cquizes". For example

```
cquizes.tb_depts
```

Its seems to use the database that matches the datasource name. Is there a way to work around this functionality.

Comment: Could you create a view in database1 that selects the table in database2, then use the view in your model?

Comment: haven't tried that, let me try and I will reply back the results

Comment: I would say that that is a use case where it's worth going back to cfquery. Wheels doesn't prevent that - nothing wrong in wrapping a cfquery in a  function like `getQuizzes()` to get what you need. `controller.cfc` can be a good place for those sort of functions.

Comment: @Dan, that seems to work but other problems is that is says "No primary key exists on the view_tb_depts table."

Comment: @Dan, My view has the sql; SELECT "ID","UNIT","DEPT","CLASS" FROM CQUIZES.TB_DEPTS. No sure if a view is suppose to have a primary key

Comment: @Dan, the TD_DEPTS table has a primary key on the ID in its database

Answer (score 1):

If you need to get data from another database, There is an alternative way. For that you need to create a datasource for your second database **cquizes**. Then use that datasource name in the model file. This will override default datasource for that model.

For example, If you name your second datasource as **cquizdatasource** then in your model would be like

```
<cfcomponent extends="Model">
    <cffunction name="init">
        <cfset dataSource("cquizdatasource")>
        <cfset table("tb_depts")>
    </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

Your query should work fine with the said scenario in the question. There are limitations to this, [check out the link](http://docs.cfwheels.org/docs/using-multiple-data-sources) to know more.

Comment: @SaadA What error it gave? can you post the error you have encountered?

Comment: It says datasource cannot be reached. What I ended doing is plain old cfquery.

Comment: The closest I got was using @dan answer able using the view. but then it says something about primary key missing.

Comment: @SaadA, Interesting. This approach should work. There might be something else going wrong. Sometimes CF gives weired error than actual error.

Comment: Hey thanks for trying to help. I realized the wording of my question was confusing so I edited. Please let me know if you help